# Auto Start MAMP Pro on System Boot?

Tags: mamp

I have [MAMP Pro](https://www.mamp.info/en/mamp-pro/).

How can I enable MAMP Pro Servers to automatically start on reboot?

Answer (score 7):

In MAMP Pro Version 4.5 (and still in 5.5.x) this option is located under Ports.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! WHY IS IT UNDER PORTS?! That makes no sense to my brain, they should just put it in `Preferences`.

Answer (score 2):

[image: mamp automatic start]

first check that box
then go to system preferences -> users & groups -> login items -> plus button 
add your mamp pro from applications folder 
that's all :)

Comment: This is totally out of date unfortunately. The answer below solves it, this one probably doesn't apply to anyone anymore and the new setting is in a radically different spot.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

On MAMP PRO v3 this configuration will start it automatically and ensure Apache and Mysql are always on.

Comment: Like most of the other answers, this one is totally out of date and probably better removed since it's unlikely many people are still using MAMP Pro 3.

Answer (score 0):

In MAMP PRO 6 this option is in preferences under the server tab.

[image]
[image]

Make sure you click save in the MAMP PRO application window after making the change.